# Infinispan transactions with @Transactional

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, infinispan

I am considering to use Infinispan as a replacement for my relational database in wildfly.

CDI supports the `@Transactional` annotation. Normally, I put `@Transactional` on method level only for JPA related transactions. Will infinispan make use of `@Transactional` (with its Java Transaction API). Or is `@Transactional` only for JPAs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Infinispan supports *JTA* and CDI supports *JTA* too, so when the CDI's Transaction Interceptor execute, it will take the Transaction Manager and create a transaction. If your Infinispan cache has configured this Transaction Manager, the resource will be enlisted/syncrhonized to the transaction.

You need to configure a *TransactionManager* to Infinispan like documentation says (Infinispan ships with several transaction manager lookup classes that can helps). For more info about this: ([Infinispan doc reference](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#transaction_manager)).

Take in mind that if you wish to mix in a same transaction multiple resources like a database and a cache and you wish to do this in a single transaction, Infinispan supports distributed transactions too so you can configure a XA transaction (in that case your database or other resource must to support XA too). More information about this: [Infinispan doc reference 2](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#tx_sync_enlist) and [Infinispan doc reference 3](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#tx_recovery)

Comment: I do not need XA-support: I will drop my "MySql" and replace that by "Infinispan" which is then my primary and only database. I only need one infinispan-node so I could run it in embeeded mode. Infinispan provides "native persistency" by its **cache stores**. I think I must use REPEATABLE_READ. I hope, I will not get any negative surprises after I replaced the relational database with Infinispan..for example, regarding ACID or storage stability. If you can share some information or links about the stumbling blocks to switching from relational db to infinispan, then let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, nemo, I never did this, so I can't help you in that way, I usually use Infinispan to mitigate database access, and to store in memory shared data.